# Add condition related to sysctl value in bash file

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to execute something only when sysctl vm.max_map_count value is less than 262144.
something like:

```
if [ vm.max_map_count -lt 262144]
then
  sysctl -w vm.max_map_count = 262144
fi
```

the question is, how to read the value of vm.max_map_count in bash.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command:

```
sysctl -n vm.max_map_count
```

prints the value without printing the key name. To use the value as an argument to another command, you need [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```
if [ "$(sysctl -n vm.max_map_count)" -lt 262144 ]
then …
```

Note there's a space before `]`. Remember `[` is a regular command (like `ls` or `echo`), *not* a part of shell syntax; and `]` is just the last argument. The `[` command *requires* its last argument to be `]`. I'm mentioning this because in your original code the last argument is `262144]`, it's syntactically wrong.

Also `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count = 262144` will not work. The right syntax is `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`.

Answer (score 0):

#### I would like to execute something only when `sysctl vm.max_map_count` value is less than `262144`.

Try the following:

```
if [ "$max_map_count" -lt 262144 ]; then sysctl -w vm.max_map_count = 262144; fi
```

Source: [if Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/if.html)

Or:

```
[[ $max_map_count -lt 262144  ]] && sysctl -w vm.max_map_count = 262144
```

Source: [test Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/test.html)

Comment: $max_map_count returns nothing...

Comment: So you need to get it first ...

Comment: That's the question :) how can i get it from sysctl  ?